# Vpn double speed but same time

Tags: gnome, 18.04, vpn, downloads

This is more a question about how the system works than a practical problem.

When I try to download something I get the same flat speed, let's say 10MB, but when I use a VPN the gnome speed applet shows double of the speed I get but (and this is the fascinating part) the time need to complete the download remains the same:

Why? Is it about Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: **:-/** What do you mean by "The speed doubles"  Where do you see this speed? (it's probably a bug in the indicator if the time remains the same)

Comment: gnome speed applet

Comment: Still on Unity here...  Added tag. Next time, please use your [Shift] key for correct CaPiTaLiSaTiOn!  :-)

Comment: What speed does the download tool show? I'm guessing the indicator shows traffic on both the VPN interface and the real interface, thus indicating double traffic...